# Signin with Twitter stopped working suddenly

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have a web application which uses Twitter's OAUTH to login users. I am using Twitter4J version 2.1.11

This application has been working flawlessly and stopped working very recently, possibly in the past couple of weeks.

```
public static void authWithTwitter() {
    try {           
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(getTwitterCallbackUrl());
        // save requestToken for retreival after user logs in 
            // code not shown for brevity
        redirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        cLogger.error("Could not perform pre twitter login steps", e);
    }
}
```

This code would (till the app was working) redirect the user to Twitter's login page, which upon successful authentication, would call the callback url.

However, recently, this has stopped working and I get the following Exception.

```
401:Authentication credentials (http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8dda30a8 or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=68161d96
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8dda30a8-68161d96], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.11}
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:199)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:112)
        at twitter4j.http.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:148)
        at twitter4j.TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterOAuthSupportBaseImpl.java:88)
        at twitter4j.Twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Twitter.java:58)
```

I did some searching and verified that I have the callback url set properly in my app's settings in dev.Twitter.com

I have not yet re-generated the key and consumer secret, but that would be the next step if I cannot get it to work.

Does anyone have a clue, why this would stop working ?

Comment: Did you verify that the clock is set correctly?

Comment: @abraham Thanks I will check the clock. This link (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1043) suggests that my server's clock should be within 5 minutes of their clock... will check that. Thanks.

Comment: @abraham The server's clock has become off but more than 5 minutes. I am really surprised that a virtual server's clock could lag behind. This probably accumulated slowly and exceeded 5 minutes. You were right. Can you please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks Parag.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the servers clock is set correctly. If it is more than a few minutes off from Twitter's requests will fail.