# Suddenly code to get twitter login url stopped working

Tags: php, twitter, zend-framework2, twitter-oauth

Suddenly the code to get Twitter login URL stopped working.

Error returned by generated URL to get `outh_token` is:

> `<error code="32">Could not authenticate you.</error>`

URL generated to get `outh_token` is:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http://project.local.com/dashboard/redirect-from-twitter&oauth_consumer_key=if5hivS82GJURRJMp60CjXQVd&oauth_nonce=1426244533&oauth_signature=Ag16Q1uwiiAJsLu5Zbl3oy1hil4%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1426244533&oauth_version=1.0
```

It seems as if something is wrong with signature.

Following is my code to generate signature:

```
public function buildsignature($method, $params, $url, $access_token_secret = null)
{
    $keys = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_keys($params));
    $values = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(array_values($params));
    $params = array_combine($keys, $values);
    uksort($params, 'strcmp');

    // convert params to string
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        $pairs[] = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($k) . '=' . $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($v);
    }
    $concatenatedParams = implode('&', $pairs);

    // form base string (first key)
    $baseString = $method . "&" . $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($url) . "&" . $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($concatenatedParams);
    // form secret (second key)

    if ($access_token_secret) {

        $key_parts = array(
            self::CLIENT_SECRET,
            $access_token_secret
        );
        $key_parts = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($key_parts);
        $secret = implode('&', $key_parts);

            //$secret = rawurlencode(self::CLIENT_SECRET) . '&' . rawurlencode($access_token_secret);
        } else {
             $secret = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986(self::CLIENT_SECRET)."&";
        }

        return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $secret, TRUE));
}
```

I tried answers from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861756/signin-with-twitter-stopped-working-suddenly
```

But I'm testing it on my local system, so I hope that there isn't due to any time gap. It's not creating the URL to be used for login purpose.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to make it work again, I want to get twitter login url. It was working but not now.

Comment: What changed? Something must have changed.

Comment: Yeah it could be but I don't understand whats wrong as it was working few days back.

Comment: You will not know until you know what has changed. Code doesn't go from working to not working without changes.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but I checked my code, I can't see anything wierd in my code. But error message returned from twitter api is <error code="32">Could not authenticate you.</error>.

I tried by creating new app token as well.

Comment: Are you sure something hasn't changed on Twitter's side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72925/discussion-between-vipul-sharma-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: Apologies, I cannot enter chat from this location.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - lots of users are complaining that my app no longer work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my code and replaced:

```
$pairs[] = $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($k) . '=' . $this->_urlencode_rfc3986($v);
```

with

```
$pairs[] = $k . '=' . $v;
```

where $this->_urlencode_rfc3986() is

```
public function _urlencode_rfc3986($input)
{
        if (is_array($input)) {
            return array_map($this->_urlencode_rfc3986, $input);
        }
        else if (is_scalar($input)) {
            return str_replace('+',' ',str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($input)));
        }
        else{
            return '';
        }
}
```

Now that's crazy because that previous code was working from last few months, it stopped suddenly. But the question is how could someone find such issues.